# Appending a line to an image in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, image, opencv, append

Say I have an image of dimensions 40 x 39. I need to add a line to the image so the final image is 40 x 40 in dimensions. And how can I do this horizontally and vertically?

I tried,

```
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
blank_image = np.zeros((1, 40, 3), np.float32)
img = np.concatenate((img, blank_image), axis=1)
```

But this gives me this error,

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As here says [numpy.concatenate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) The arrays must have the same shape, except in the dimension corresponding to axis (the first, by default).

Try creating the blank_image with the same shape than img except in the dimension of the axis (in this case I think that is the two)

```
shape = img.shape
shape = list(shape)
#axis dimmension
shape[1] = 1
shape = tuple(shape)
blank_image = np.zeros(shape, np.float32)
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Had to edit the code a bit since tuples are immutable.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use  function cv.copyMakeBorder() [Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=copymakeborder#copymakeborder) function from OpenCV to append a row or column 
by just giving  the  desired the values to  top , down , left , right  argumnets

```
def createBorder( ):
global img # image in which we want to append
borderType = cv.BORDER_CONSTANT
TDLU=[0 , 1, 0 , 1 ]#top,down,left,right values 
img = cv.copyMakeBorder(img, TDLU[0] , TDLU[1] , TDLU[2] , TDLU[3] , borderType, None, 255)
row, col = img.shape
print(row, col)
```